# Make potentially asynchronous RxJS observable certainly asynchronous

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

There is potentially asynchronous observable, i.e. something like:

```
const potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable = [
  Observable.of('sync'),
  Observable.of('async').delay(100)
][Math.round(Math.random())];

potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable.subscribe(console.log);
```

It should be made asynchronous observable. It's desirable to not delay it any further if it's already asynchronous, so I can't do `potentiallyButNotNecessarilyAsyncObservable.delay(0)`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you better explain what differences do you see in "sync" and "async" Observables?

Comment: As I know there are no "sync" Observables, because you can't retrieve it values without subscribing and passing callback which will be executed asynchronously(depending on your Scheduler)

Comment: @OlesSavluk A 'sync' observable is shown in the example above. `Observable.of('sync').subscribe(...)` will emit a value immediately, on same tick.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the way how work will be scheduled and executed by using Schedulers. For example, you can write `.observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.async)` and work will be scheduled using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instead of synchronous recursive calls. This is advanced topic and if you would like to know it better I recomend you to read [this great documentation on Schedulers](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md)

Here are the two examples, first is executed in one tick and the second in several:

```js
const { of, asapScheduler } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { observeOn } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const sync$ = of('sync');

// by default RxJS will pick a default scheduler by using the principle of least concurrency
// in this case it is a null or undefined Schedulr which means notifications are delivered synchronously and recursively
console.log('--------- default(null) Scheduler ---------------');
console.log('just before subscribe');
sync$.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
console.log('just after subscribe');


const async$ = sync$.pipe(
  observeOn(asapScheduler)
);

// "got value sync" is printed after "just after subscribe"
console.log('--------- Rx.Scheduler.async Scheduler ----------');
console.log('just before subscribe');
async$.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
console.log('just after subscribe');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the question referred to the behaviour provided by default scheduler. Indeed, `Scheduler.async` is the solution. Thanks.